# How to add articles to a group in Jabref?

Tags: bibtex

I'm new to Jabref, coming from Mendeley, and trying to recreate the grouped article structure I had in Mendeley. I've created several groups, but when I try to add an article to them, either via drag-and-drop or via selecting the article and right-clicking on the group and selecting "Add selected to group", nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening. When I created the group, I created an "Add articles by keyword" group. I tried creating a new "Explicit selection" group (in the "Collect by" section of the group creation dialogue), and **was** able to add articles to that group. I was also able to convert an existing add-by-keyword group to explicit-selection (via right-clicking on the group and selecting "edit group"), and was then able to add articles to it.

So I guess you can only manually add articles to a group you created  with, or converted to, "Explicit Selection."